# How to make an arrow to a box

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, callout

I have a beamer slide where I want to show the meaning of a variable by adding a box with an arrow to the variable. Here is my failed attempt:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\newtcolorbox{myexample}[0]{%
    text width=2cm, text height=0.1cm, enhanced,colback=green,colframe=black, coltitle=black,boxrule=0.8mm, tikz={rotate=90,transform shape}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Therefore
    \only<1>{
    $\Pr(A, B)$ 
    }
    \only<2>{
    $\Pr(\tikz{
    \node[fill=blue!20,,ellipse, anchor=base] (t1)
    {A, B};
    })$
    }
    $=0$
    \only<2>{
    \begin{myexample}
        ${\scriptstyle 0,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9}$
    \end{myexample}
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I:

- Make the vertical tcolorbox be right aligned at the vertical position of my choosing?
- Draw a bendy arrow from the tcolorbox to the ellipse around $A, B$ in the second transition only
- Make the text in the tcolorbox be centred in the box.  `text height = 0.1cm` can't be right either but it was the only way I could make the box smaller and it still isn't quite small enough.
- Make the ellipse smaller, vertically centred correctly and so that the text around it doesn't move when it is added?

Sorry for the  large number of quesions.

[image]

---

Ultimately I would like to use it in this beamer slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{myexample}[2][]{%
    text width=\textwidth-1cm, text height=2.5cm, enhanced,colback=white,colframe=black, coltitle=black,
    sharp corners,boxrule=0.8mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.3\baselineskip-0.4pt,xshift=2mm},
    boxed title style={tile,size=minimal,left=0.5mm,right=0.5mm,
        colback=white,before upper=\strut},
    title=#2,#1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

\begin{myexample}[text height=3cm]{}
    Suppose you pick a uniformly random integer from $\{1, \dots, 100\}$. If $A$ is the event that the last digit is a $3$ then $\Pr(A) = 1/10$.  If $B$ is the event that the number is prime then $\Pr(B) = 1/4$. 
    \[ 
    \Pr(A \mid B) = \frac{\Pr(A, B)}{\Pr(B)} = \frac{7/100}{1/4} = \frac{28}{100}
    \] 
\end{myexample}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One idea is not to use tcolorboxes, but doing all in tikZ. You can simply define all types of boxes there. With the node at statement you may arrange all items well.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein. That's sounds good. I only just learned how to use tcolorbox!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `tikz` and `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes,
                tikzmark}

                            
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tikzset{baseline,
 E/.style={ellipse, fill=gray!30, inner sep=2pt, anchor=base},
 N/.style={draw=green!60!black, very thick, rounded corners, fill=green!30,
           font=\scriptsize, rotate=90, anchor=east}
        }
\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex} % <--- approximation of the equation height
Therefore
\only<1>{
    $\Pr(A, B)$
            }% <---
\only<2>{
    $\Pr(\tikz[baseline]\node[E] {\subnode{a}{A, B}};) =0$
% <---
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node (b) [N]
        at (current page.center)
        {0,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    \draw[-Stealth, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm]
        (a) to [bend right] (b.north); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
            }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: For above result you need to compile MWE (at least) twice.

*Edit*: A wee bit improved code. Now the vertical position of equation is the same on the both slides.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach to get what you may want with tikZ:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \only<1,2>{%
        \node [minimum height=20pt] (T1) at (0,0) {Therefore $\Pr($};
        \node [minimum height=20pt] (T2) at (1.6,0) {$A, B$};
        \node [minimum height=20pt] (T3) at (2.5,0) {$)= 0$};
        }
        \only<2>{%
        \node [%
            fill=green,
            draw,
            rounded corners=5pt,
            rotate=90,
            anchor=east,
            text height=11pt
            ]
            (X) at (0.25,-0.75) {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        \draw [->, thick, blue] (X.south) to [in=-90, out=0] (T2.south);
        \node [%
            minimum height=20pt,
            ellipse,
            x radius=0.5,
            y radius=1,
            fill=blue!20!white,
            inner sep=0
            ]
            (T2) at (1.6,0) {$A, B$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Simply with `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Therefore
    \only<1>{
    $\Pr(A, B)$
    }
    \only<2>{
    $\Pr\bigl(\!\ovalnode[linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=blue!20,] {E}{A, B}\!\bigr)$
    }
    $=0$

    \only<2>{%
\rotatebox[origin=lB]{90}{
        $\scriptstyle \pnode{A}0,1,2,3,4,\rnode{R}{4},5,6,7,8,9\pnode{B}\ncbox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=SeaGreen!65, linearc=0.1, boxsize=1.5ex, nodesep=2pt]{A}{B}
\rput[l](A){\scriptstyle 0, 1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9}$
}
    }
\nccurve[arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesepA=1.5ex, angleB=-150]{R}{E}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain `\pnode{A}0,1,2,3,4,\rnode{R}{4},5,6,7,8,9\pnode{B}` please (the 4 is accidentally duplicated too).  What part do A, R and B play?

Comment: It is quite simple: the \pnodes are empty nodes placed before 0 and after 9, and have names A and B respectively. As \rnode, it makes the second 4 a node (rectangular) and I name it R. Then I connect the empty nodes  by an `\ncbox` connection,  Normally, it connects them with a framebox (with rounded corners in the present case), but I also fill it  with green, and the numbers are no more visible,  so I place them again at the left empty node (which is at the bottom after the rotation. The node R is at the centre of the box,, and I connect it to the oval node with a Bézier curve (\nccurve).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Is it completely clear now?

Comment: Thank you. I will need to read the manual of pst-node but your answer is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Like this ?

I commented the code with `%<--` to explain the changes.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\newtcolorbox{myexample}[0]{%
    width=4.5cm,%<-- width of the tcbox
    halign=center,%<-- align of text
    text height=0.1cm,enhanced,colback=green,colframe=black,
    % coltitle=black, <-- useless option
    boxrule=0.8mm, tikz={rotate=90,transform shape}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{overlayarea}{0.9\textwidth}{0.4\textheight}% <- reserved area of the tikzpicture
Therefore\;\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \node  [anchor=base] (t1){ $\Pr(A,B)=0$};%<- the node is around math text
    \fill<2>[blue!40,fill opacity=.5%<-- the ellipse is build over the node with fill opacity=.5
    ] ([shift={(-4pt,.7pt)}]t1)% <- shift to center the ellipse on the node
     circle[x radius=4mm,y radius=2.2mm];
    \node<2>[below right= 5 mm and 5mm of t1] %<-- with positioning library second node is relative of first node
    (t2){
    \begin{myexample}
        ${\scriptstyle 0,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9}$
    \end{myexample}
    } edge[->,out=180,in=-70,very thick] (t1.south);%<-- arrow from tcbox to text
    
    \end{tikzpicture}   
 \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this tutorial style answer!